# Verilog testbench comparison

Tags: verilog, fault

I have the results of five circuit simulations with some tests, and the result is to be noted in a fault table.

Now I have to compare the values generated from a new circuit with the values that I already have from the above circuit simulations. I am doing this so to know from which fault class does my new circuit is.

How do I store the value of my previous simulations in the testbench and how do I compare my new values to the previous stored results in the same testbench and the fault class it matches I have to print that fault class?

So basically I want to know how to do comparison.

Comment: Are you running the two at the same time?  Or running one, then later running another?  If the answer is #1, you can store them in some shared variable or object that you create.  If the answer is #2, you'll have to use files.

Answer (score 3):

One easy way is to dump the values you are interested in in a text file. You can time stamp (or print the clock cycle number) at each line. A simple diff, perl script or programs like meld and [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) can be used to compare the two files and to find out at what time or on which clock cycles the values are different.